# How to calculate total storage consumption in a Azure subscription

Tags: powershell, azure, cloud, azure-powershell, iaas

I am trying to figure out if there is any way to find out total storage consumed in a Azure subscription, either via PowerShell or may be OMS. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried it myself but from reading the article you should be able to use some of his Powershell code.
http://www.azurefieldnotes.com/2017/03/12/how-to-calculate-azure-vhds-used-space/

Answer (score 0):

You can see the percentage of storage Accounts consumed/used in Azure portal by navigating to below location.

Subscriptions--> Usage + quotas --> Storage Accounts.

[image: Azure Usage & quotas]